# Switching between or adding multiple VOLTTRON Historian Framework

Tags: mongodb, volttron

I have below agent installed in my Volttron platform:

> AGENT      -       IDENTITY      -      TAG
>
> sqlhistorianagent-3.6.1 -  platform.historian    - platform_historian

Following the documentation: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/core_services/historians/index.html

I tried to install another Historian -(**Mongo Historian**) following this doc.:http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/core_services/historians/Mongo-Historian.html#prerequisites

Below the steps followed to install mongodb on Ubuntu:

**Prerequisites**

1.Mongodb

```
cd volttron
. env/bin/activate
sudo scripts/historian-scripts/root_install_mongo_ubuntu.sh
```

2.Mongodb connector

`pip install pymongo`

The installation done successfully. However, I am using below commands to check the status of the installed agent.

```
volttron -l log1&
volttron-ctl status
```

For some reason, it is not showing up under my agents.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have both agents in the same Volttron? if it is not,
please let me know how to switch between the historian agents (i.e replace Sqlhistorianagent with Mongodbagent) or enable Mongodbagent agent?

*It is worth-mentioning that I have "Crate Historian" installed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pymongo is required for connecting to the mongo database.  You still need to install the MongodbHistorian.

You can look at https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/master/scripts/historian-scripts/start-historian-mysql.sh for an example of what you will need to do to install the agent itself.  The following assumes that you are running it from the root of the volttron directory and that you have modified the config file in the mongodbhistorian directory to connect to your mongodb instance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -e "./volttron/platform" ]; then
    echo "Please execute from root of volttron repository."
    exit 0
fi

export HIST="services/core/MongodbHistorian"
export HIST_CONFIG="$HIST/config.mongodb"
SCRIPTS_CORE="./scripts/core"

$SCRIPTS_CORE/start_historian.sh $1
```

One thing also to note is that shortly we will be updating master to releases/5.0rc so the methodology for installations will have changed.

Comment: Thanks Craig! My OS is ubuntu, using this command sudo scripts/historian-scripts/root_install_mongo_ubuntu.sh it seems there is some missing personal packages for instance, (http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu) this is and error message I am getting...                                                                  E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found   ..... and E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.