# VOLTTRON : Mongodb installation- error in ppa chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, failed-installation, volttron

My OS is: Ubuntu (16.04 LTS)

> I want to install **MongoDB historian** instead of **mysqlhistorian**
>   (installed).

Following up the issue: [Switching between or adding multiple VOLTTRON Historian Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860971/switching-between-or-adding-multiple-volttron-historian-framework)

and the documentation: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/core_services/historians/Mongo-Historian.html#prerequisites

it seems that there is another error occur when I run the script :

`sudo scripts/historian-scripts/root_install_mongo_ubuntu.sh`

This message shows up:

`Enter 1 or 2 based on the version of Ubuntu you are running`

`1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(Precise Pangolin)`

`2. Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS(Trusty Tahr)`

> I select "2", because it is the closest version to (16.04 LTS)

after selecting "2"

I get the error shown below:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.0w3KEgvSfT/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
EA312927
gpg: requesting key EA312927 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key EA312927: "MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:            unchanged: 1
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release          
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:4 http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                       
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial Release        
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

## Note

> It is worth mentioning I have installed (pyzmq) using:
>
> (Volttron)USER_NAME@USER_NAME-Laptop:~/volttron$ `pip install pyzmq` and the requirement for it is satisfied as shown below:
>
> `Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in
>   ./env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
>
> and for (MongoDB connector) is also satisfied using :`pip install pymongo`
>
> `Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

## Question

- If selecting "2" is not correct, what is the solution for higher Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script needs to be updated to support the latest version of ubuntu. I will update it and create a pull request.

As an alternative have you considered CrateHistorian? CrateHistorian also provides better performance for large production systems.

Comment: Thank you so much schandrika, Yes I used CrateHistorian and it works smoothly.